# JTA How to get the current transaction(JNDI?, ServiceLoader?)? To register a Synchronization

Tags: java, jta

I have a small custom library that needs to be transactional.
In order to support JTA I want to implement and publish a Synchronization(I want to keep it simple, therefore no XAResource).

1: Can I throw an exception(OptimisticLocking) in beforeCompletion?

However when I open my transactional resource in a thread I need to register it on the current JTA transaction.
At first I thought this is possible by using the TransactionSynchronizationRegistry.
But this seems to be the key value store I should use for my transaction local data.

2: Is the TransactionSynchronizationRegistry used in order to support transaction suspend/resume?

So in order to register my Synchronization I need the JTA Transaction(or the TransactionManager which can give me the current transaction).
According to the javadoc of JTA 1.1 there are no JNDI lookups to resolve it and no hints on using a java ServiceLoader.

3: Does this mean that resolving the current Transaction is Provider dependent?

4: Is there a standard, provider independent way of resolving the current Transaction? (if not, I will provide a consumer interface and use the ServiceLoader infrastructure to resolve its implementations. So the integrating developer is responsible to provide a way to resolve the transaction)

Comment: Which JTA implementation do you want to use?

Comment: I want to stay independent of any JTA implementation, if that is possible.

Comment: Afaik JTA is mostly provided by frameworks. For Spring see: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-jta.html - it seems to be implementation agnostic, but comes with the tradeoff of introducing Spring.